# How to align captions of subtables with the left margin of a minipage?

Tags: tables, koma-script, minipage

I have a `minipage` of width `\textwidth`. Inside of that `minipage` are two other `minipages` of width `0.5\textwidth`. Each of those has a `\tabular` environment with a caption (made with `KOMA-scripts'` `\captionof` command). My table looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

i.e. I want to align the caption of table `(b)` to the left (margin of the nested `minipage`).

MWE (the caption for the subtables is within `\NewDocumentEnvironment{subtable}{m m b}`):

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass[
 fleqn,
 oneside, 
 headings = optiontoheadandtoc,
 fontsize = 12pt, 
 parskip = never,
 numbers = noendperiod,
 captions = abovetable,
 ]{scrbook}

\interdisplaylinepenalty=1000

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xpatch}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{cmun}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*rm,
    ItalicFont=*ti,
    BoldFont=*bx,
    BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,IEEEtrantools,latexsym,mathdots,mathtools,upgreek,xfrac}

\usepackage[lowtilde]{url}
\usepackage[unicode, colorlinks, bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}  

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
    
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\newcommand{\hidefromtoc}{\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}}
\newcommand{\writetotoc}{\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline}

\newcounter{subtableCounter}
\newcounter{subfigureCounter}
\newcounter{tempCounterForFiguresAndTables}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{subTables}{m m b}
{%
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    \centering
    % --- Main table caption ---
    \addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand*{\tableformat}{\hfil\tablename~\thetable\hfil}
    \renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
    \setcapindent*{0em}
    \captionof{table}{#1}
    \label{table:#2}
    \setcaphanging % restore regular caption indent for the subcaptions
    % ----------------------------------------
    % --- Set up counter for the subtables ---
    \setcounter{tempCounterForFiguresAndTables}{\value{table}}
    \setcounter{subtableCounter}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{(\alph{subtableCounter})}
    \renewcommand*{\tableformat}{\thetable\ }
    % ----------------------------------------
        #3
    \end{minipage}
    \par
    %
    % --- Restore table counter to normal ---
    \renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}
    \setcounter{table}{\value{tempCounterForFiguresAndTables}}
}
{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{subtable}{m m b}
{%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
        {\centering
        #3
        \par}
        %
        % --- Subtable caption ---
        \hidefromtoc
        \vspace*{0.5em}
        \captionof{table}{#1}
        \label{subtable:#2}
        \writetotoc
        \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\hskip 0.7em\thetable\autodot\ #1}
        \refstepcounter{subtableCounter}
\end{minipage}%
}
{}


\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \chapter{Test}
    \section{Test}
    \counterwithout{table}{chapter}
    \begin{subTables}{Here we provide a description that is really long for testing purposes. Look how long this description is.}{tagTable1}%
        \begin{subtable}{Another really long description that spans multiple lines.}{tagSubtable1}
            \begin{tabular}{c | r @{.} l} 
                $\sin(x)$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} \\
                \hline
                $\sin(0)$           & 0&0 \\
                $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$       & 0&707
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}%
        \begin{subtable}{Description}{tagSubtable2}
            \begin{tabular}{c | r @{.} l} 
                $\cos(x)$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} \\
                \hline
                $\cos(0)$           & 1&0 \\
                $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})$       & 0&707
            \end{tabular}
        \end{subtable}%
    \end{subTables}%            
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for defining your own subtable environment instead of using the one provided by `subcaption`?

Comment: Also, why do you decide to use 2 columns in order to align your numbers with respect to the decimal marker? Why not use the `S` txpe column from the `siunitx` package for this?

Comment: Regarding the alignment itself, using `\usepackage{caption}` in combination with `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` should result in the desired output.

Comment: I defined my own environment for learning purposes. Also, isn't subcaption only for floating environments (table, figure) or can I use it anywhere? Regarding the 2 columns. This is an example from a LaTeX book and that book also mentions siunitx but the point the book was trying to make is that things can be done in different ways. I will use siunitx in the future. Regarding the package caption. I am interested in a solution that doesn't involve additional packages but if it can't be done, I'll use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\KOMAoptions{captions=nooneline}`:

```latex
\NewDocumentEnvironment{subtable}{m m b}
{%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
        {\centering
        #3
        \par}
        %
        % --- Subtable caption ---
        \KOMAoptions{captions=nooneline}% <- added
        \hidefromtoc
        \vspace*{0.5em}
        \captionof{table}{#1}
        \label{subtable:#2}
        \writetotoc
        \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\hskip 0.7em\thetable\autodot\ #1}
        \refstepcounter{subtableCounter}
\end{minipage}%
}
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify you definition of the `subtable` environment like this:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{subtable}{m m b}
{%
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}%
        {\centering
        #3
        \par}
        %
        % --- Subtable caption ---
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
        \hidefromtoc
        \vspace*{0.5em}
        \captionof{table}{#1}
        \label{subtable:#2}
        \writetotoc
        \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\hskip 0.7em\thetable\autodot\ #1}
        \refstepcounter{subtableCounter}
\end{minipage}%
```

Comment: My goal is to rely on the stuff already provided by KOMA-script i.e. KOMA-scripts' \captionof command so I'll wait for more answers but if what I want is not possible or really hard to do, I will mark your answer as the accepted one.